# Android content provider, update with SUM

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

How can I use this query with Android content provider?

```
update tblTot set vMax = vMax + 15 where _id = 1;
```

Where vMax is a column of tblTot table.

I have tried to do this

```
Uri totUri = Uri.parse(DbProvider.TOT_CONTENT_URI + "/1");          
ContentValues valoriTotali = new ContentValues();
valoriTotali.put(DbHelper.TBTOT_VMAX, DbHelper.TBTOT_VMAX +  " + " + newVMax);
int rcdTot = resolver.update(totUri, valoriTotali, null, null);
```

But it does not work because this update set the value as string ("db column name + value") and not as integer inside my db row.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you have to add special uri for such things fx.: `DbProvider.TOT_CONTENT_URI + "Increment"` then in ContentProvider you can put `db.rawQuery("update tblTot set vMax = vMax + ? where _id = ?", new String[] {"15", "1"});` for this uri ... you can pass parameters ("15" nad "1") from uri or query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of `vMax` and cast it as `Integer`

```
//    CAST((CAST(vMax as INTEGER) +15) AS text)
```

EDIT: How to use the above line

```
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "select vMax from tblTot "
            + " where _id = 1"; 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    int vMax = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.i(Tag, "vMax: "+cursor.getString(0) );
            vMax= Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

    }
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("vMax", Integer.toString(vMax+15));
    db.update("tblTot ", values, _id + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(_id ) });
    db.Close();
```

Comment: @Selvin thanx.. you can +1 the answer

Comment: @MDMalik: Thank you, but in this way i must perform a new query.. 
I was trying to use the Selvin solution (add a line inside of ContentProvider class) but an error in another part of my code has stopped me.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to expose new URI for it(or pass additional argument in URI) and base on that take appropriate action in ContentProvider's update(), something like this -

```
case CASE_URI_INCREMENT_LIKE:
String sqlStatement = "UPDATE " + Table.TABLE_NAME + " SET " +  Table.VALUE + " = " +  Table.VALUE + " + 1 WHERE " + Table.ID + "=?";
mSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlStatement, selectionArgs);
break;
```